# Alamofire request with JSONEncoding giving an error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am getting an error while passing JSON object as a parameter in Alamofire.request

```
func apiCall2(anyBaseUrl: String = "", apiFunction: ApiName, method m: HTTPMethod = .get,
             parameters: [String: Any]? = nil, isJsonEncoding: Bool = false,
             completion:  @escaping (Bool, Any?, Error?) -> Void) {

    var requestUrl = "\(ActiveBaseURL())\(apiFunction.rawValue)"

    if anyBaseUrl != "" {
        requestUrl = "\(anyBaseUrl)\(apiFunction.rawValue)"
    }

    var param = [String: Any]()

    if let p = parameters {
        param = p
    }

    Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: m, parameters: param, encoding: isJsonEncoding ? JSONEncoding.default: URLEncoding.default)
        .authenticate(user: ApiUserName, password: ApiPassword)
        .responseJSON(options: .allowFragments) { response in
            print("request body: \(response.request?.httpBody)")
            if response.result.isSuccess {
            }
            print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)
            completion(false, nil, response.result.error)
    }
}
```

My actual JSON format is

> {   "discount_code" : "",   "giftcard_code" : "",   "dt" :
>   "2018-11-15",   "shipping" : {
>       "state" : "sel",
>       "name" : "Test",
>       "address1" : "testevhsd",
>       "city" : "test city",
>       "address2" : "testfhd",
>       "mobile" : "89464633",
>       "shipment_code" : "YES",
>       "postal" : "672673",
>       "country_id" : "129"   },   "iccid" : "",   "uid" : "3592",   "product" : [
>       {
>         "id" : 104,
>         "type" : "countryPlan",
>         "qty" : 1
>       }   ] }

And this is how I am passing the JSON in function

```
var parms: Parameters {

        return  [
            "uid": "3592",
            "product": [
                ["id": 104,"type":"countryPlan", "qty": 1]
            ],
            "shipping": ["name":"Test", "mobile": "89464633", "address1": "testevhsd",
                         "address2": "testfhd", "city": "test city", "state": "sel",
                         "postal": "672673", "shipment_code": "YES", "country_id": "129"],
            "discount_code": "",
            "dt":"2018-11-15",
            "giftcard_code": "",
            "iccid": ""]
    }

    Service.shared.apiCall2(apiFunction: .CheckOut, method: .post, parameters: parms, isJsonEncoding: true) { (success, data, _) in
```

My Error

> "JSON could not be serialized because of error:\nThe data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Initially I thought this is because of web service not able to return the correct JSON but I was wrong if I run same service from postman it is working fine and I am getting data in JSON format

I feel the error is because for JSON data passing

Comment: *The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.* is a generic error message displayed when calling `localizedDescription`. You have to print the `DecodingError`, it tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Use `responseString` and print it instead of `responseJSON`. Also in POSTMAN you can ask for Swift Code, that could highlight some missing header for instance.

Comment: I am also running into a similar intermittent issue. In your case can you share if this is permanent issue or just sometime?

Comment: @user550088, can you tell me your json payload?